# Possible concealed lethal weapons in a medieval setting

Tags: weapons, medieval, renaissance

For a character based around being invisible in a crowd and stealthy alone, what could a highly intelligent craftsmen (with abilities branching into renaissance era) what type of hidden and concealable weapons could be useful?

EDIT: They would need to end a single target is a single stealthy attack, however they need to be able to fight their way out if necessary.

Comment: It depends on how they want to use the weapons. Do they expect a fight? Are they going for ranged weapons? Something that doesn't look like a weapon? Or perhaps something that would allow them a single strike?

Comment: they would like to do a single strike on the main target however the need to be able to fight their way out if needed

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiletto

Comment: What's wrong with a knife? The problem with best weapon questions is they are entirely dependent upon context. Is the person expecting a fight, who are they expecting to fight, what are they expecting their opponent to be armed with, will either of them be wearing armor, what is the fashion of the city that they are in, is cost a factor, etc, are all factors that need to be considered when picking a weapon.

Comment: I know of the stiletto and though of giving them one and likely will however i was looking for something with a little creativity and style behind it simply for stylistic reasons. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Misericorde, hidden daggers, many daggers, throwing rondel daggers, daggers in boots, swordbreaker aaaaaand arm mounted crossbow used as a shield. In medieval you either poisoned someone or get close and personal. And if your target don't have an army you just hire some scum to beat them to pulp with bare fists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For assassination, you want poison.

The traditional dart poisons are a one option and the built in suggestion of a ranged attack is nice and... well no law against making your cane hollow, is there?

The other practical poisons are the ones such as [ricin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricin) or [abrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrin). You bump on your target and a few days later they are dead due to mysterious illness that started hours after you were anywhere near them. This has been done in real attacks by KGB and its allied services.

Poisoning their food is also possible and usually better. The real historical professional assassins usually did that. (Which is why important people had food tasters and assassins had slow poisons and kings developed their poison resistance by eating poison and...)

The problem with poisons is that they are not one hundred percent reliable since delivery methods waste an unpredictable amount of the poison.

You also seem to be want something more visible and direct. Usually this is because you want to claim credit for the kill and be seen doing it. This is actually very rare for a professional assassin but religious fanatics do that and then let themselves be killed or captured afterwards which nicely solves your second problem.

But a poisoned dagger that you hide in your clothes, and stab on something exposed and non-removable such as neck and leave in the wound (or at the scene) is also traditional. The dagger you leave behind doubles as a calling card that identifies who did it. So you want a custom design.

Poison makes the wound lethal even if the hit is not perfect and using the weapon only for a single attack increases the odds the poison actually works. The traditional fast dart poisons probably work best for this.

Since the weapon is single use and disposable it can be pretty exotic. It can for example resemble a short arrow or a dart with short and possibly barbed head and a longer wooden shaft. Weapon like this would be difficult to draw out giving the poison more chance to work and could possibly be throwable. The colors of the shaft would identify the group responsible for the attack.

As for the self-defence weapons the best would be whatever other people looking the same as the assassin use, swords could be street legal.

Still the primary defence for an assassin should always be a rapid escape, run fast and plan your escape route in advance. Be confident you can vanish into the crowd or the slums before doing anything. Wearing a distinctive assassin cloak when attacking and then not wearing it when people look for you actually does work but does make sneaking on people difficult.

Distraction devices such as smoke bombs are good. The Japanese had a device for blowing irritating powder at people as a distraction. Allies distracting the guards and securing the escape also work but mean sharing the pay. Typically a direct attack on someone with guards in public would be a team effort. The striker would draw the pursuers to the backup team which would delay the guards before themselves vanishing.

Disabling the guards before killing the target is actually the normal solution as it allows you to make sure the target really died. But it does not seem to have the flavour you want. And it does seem to devolve into street brawls between competing factions pretty easily.

As for a special but harmless looking weapon maybe a heavy cane made from hard wood. Staff type weapons are good for defence and hitting your enemies in the legs makes them unable to pursue you. Kicking them with hard shoes also works.

The main "assassin thing" is to remember that nobody paid you anything to kill the guards and working for free reduces the value of your services.

Besides the guards are just doing their work, you **want** them to think that way. A guard watching for or pursuing an assassin that kills guards will be lot more motivated and effective than a guard watching for assassin that kills annoying noble brats and gives the guards few bruises. Best case scenario, your targets will start killing and punishing the guards and their morale (and effectiveness) will collapse.

Answer (score 1):

- Blackjack
- Brass knuckles
- Monkey fist (basically a small flail)
- Needles, stillehtos, daggars
- Bear claws
- Garotte
- Short chain

And I don't think it would be beyond medieval technology to create a cane sword.  Of course, a cane made out of ironwood would also be a remarkable weapon...

Comment: This reads quite a bit like the weapon list off a certain assassin game lol, some of these might be good additions too his arsenal though. Thanks for the input!